# Kafka listener - Is it possible to acknowledge message in DefaultErrorHandler , when ACK mode is set to MANUAL_IMMEDIATE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, deprecation-warning

I created kafka listener with `ACK mode` set to `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`.

I'm using DefaultErrorHandler and DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer to retry message few times and if it still fails send it to other topic.

```
BackOff fixedBackOff = new FixedBackOff(2000, 3);
DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer = new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate,
            (kafkaRecord, exception) -> new TopicPartition("OTHER-TOPIC", kafkaRecord.partition()));
DefaultErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(recoverer, fixedBackOff);
```

Is it possible to acknowledge failed message after I send it to other topic.
I don't want to have duplicates or lost messages.

I tried to pass Acknowledgment object in exception - but original exception is replaced by  ListenerExecutionFailedException.

Also I found that `setRecoveryCallback` method is **Deprecated**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container automatically acks recovered messages (even with manual ack mode) by default (since 2.5.3).

```java
/**
 * Set to false to prevent the container from committing the offset of a recovered
 * record (when the error handler does not itself throw an exception).
 * @param ack false to not commit.
 */
default void setAckAfterHandle(boolean ack) {
```

Comment: Its strange. When I use  DefaultErrorHandler, even when I set  "setAckAfterHandle" true. I posted massage that fails -> retries are done but current offset is not changing on kafka broker - on lag and log-end-offset is incrementing.

Comment: Looks like defaultErrorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true) is doing the job :)

Comment: Oh, right; I forgot about that.